# SSIS - Inserting records only if they don't already exist based on matching at least 1 of multiple columns

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is supposed to insert data from a flat-file into a database table. For the sake of this example, let's say I am wanting to insert `User` records. The data records come from other existing databases, so they already include a previously generated primary ID, which we would like to preserve and continue using. The records also include an email field which should also be unique in the destination table; this is enforced by the schema. A given batch could include records that have previously been "migrated" as well as a user might be in more than one of the original systems with the same email address. In addition to avoiding errors, I would also like to track any possible duplicates (on either the UserID OR the email fields) by writing those to a file.

Because matches can be made on either of the 2 fields, do I need to chain 2 Lookup Transformations? Or is there a way to specify OR operation instead of AND when using multiple columns? Or is there a better-suited transform that I should be using?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your target database system?

Comment: I always recommend loading into a staging table and doing these operations in SQL.

Comment: @UmairRamzan It's SQL Server

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Unfortunately, a staging table is not an option for this project as I do not own the target DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's split your question.

#### Can I do a Lookup with OR condition on two fields?

Yes, you can.
Suppose you are lookup through `User` table. On the Lookup transformation *General* section - specify *Partial cache* or *No cache* as *Cache mode*. Then design your query in *Connection* section. **Important** -- map your data flow fields to query columns in *Columns* section. So far preparation is done.
Go to *Advanced* section and tick *Modify the SQL statement* flag. Modify the SQL statement below with something like

```
    select * from (SELECT [ColA], [ColB], ...
          FROM [User]) [refTable]
    where [refTable].[ColA] = ? OR [refTable].[ColB] = ?
```

Then - hit *Parameters* button and specify data flow columns which should be mapped to the first `?` - *Parameter0*, and so on.
As you see, it is possible but not easy.

#### Should you use two lookups or single complex lookup?

I would go for two lookups, as it allows you finer control and error reporting - with `OR` statement you can only report that something among unique fields matched. Doing specific lookups allow you to be more specific and design special flow steps if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In my case, it is not necessary to distinguish between duplicates based on which field is matched, so a single lookup should be sufficient and will be more performant.